# Crystal report add dollar symbol

Tags: crystal-reports

In the crystal report, there are many transactions. I have taken the transactions from the database excel. Only one transactions I need to display in dollar symbol in front of the amount. If I given the dollar symbol entire transactions shows a dollar symbol. I need to show only one transaction in dollar symbol. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Does the single record has an attribute where you can recognize this one should has a dollar sign or not?

If there is an attribute you can use a formula and do something like this:

```
If {showDollar} Then "$" + ToText({amount}, 0, ',', '.') Else ToText({amount}, 0, ',', '.')
```